# How to add files to an App Group shared directory?

Tags: ios, permissions, filesystems, ios8-share-extension, bundle-identifier

So I have an app with a share extension each with their own target. The core of the apps' bundle identifier is `com.company.app` and the share extensions is `com.company.app.share`. Each have their own entitlements file, with the core apps being `App Groups -> group.com.company.app` and the share extension being the same. Both of the bundle identifiers are listed on the apple developer website but for some reason,

I don't seem to have the right permissions to write to the shared `private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/Library/Caches/` directory.

The error message I get is:
`You don’t have permission to save the file “Caches” in the folder “Library”.`

The directory is being saved like this:

```
GetZipURLInItems(self.extensionContext.inputItems, ^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {

        NSURL *containerURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:GroupIdentifier] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/Caches"];
        NSLog(@"EXT: containerURL: %@", containerURL);

        [WPZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:[url path] toDestination:[containerURL absoluteString]];

        [self listDirectoryAtPath:[containerURL absoluteString]];
    }});
```

What am I'm missing here?

Comment: How are you trying to write to it? Look at using NSFileManager:containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier

Comment: @Essenceofchickens I updated the original question to show how I'm saving the dir.

Comment: Have you tried it without the URLByAppendingPathComponent: part?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue was actually using [url absoluteString] vs [url path], changing all the urls to path solved the permissions error.